# params hash for requests different from get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

At the url `application.co/users/2` I have a form for deleting a relationship between `current_user` and `user 2`. The code for the form is:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id), html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

The destroy action of the Relationship controller is:

```
  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(user)
    redirect_to user
  end
```

Why does the action rely on the assumption that `params[:id]` represents the id of the relationship? I thought that `params[:id]` represented the number 2 in the url. 
See [link1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#code-unfollow_form) and [link2](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#code-relationships_controller_following) at the Michael Hartl's tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Because you initialize `form_for` with object of `Relationship` class not `User` class.

There is returning `Relationship` object

`current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @user.id)`